# .NET Core 3.1 IdentityServer4: getting invalid access token when using Resource Owner Password Credentials grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to get an access token from Identity Provider using Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type. The same configuration worked for .NET Core 2.2, but it doesn't work anymore for .NET Core 3.1. Here is the configuration of Identity Provider:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly string _MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "fooorigin";
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        _env = env;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddPersistence(Configuration); //Custom extension
        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseMappingProfile)));

        #region Options
        services.Configure<IdentityServerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerOptions"));
        services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
        #endregion

        #region Configurations
        services.AddTransient<IdentityServerOptions>();
        #endregion

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<ITokenManagerHelper, TokenManagerHelper>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(_MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CommonValidator>();
            fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        var identityServerDataDBConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerConfigDatabase");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(UsersDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        var identityAuthority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:Authority");

        // Add Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
           })
          .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
          {
              options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:Authority");
              options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ClientName");
              options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ClientSecret");
              options.ResponseType = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ResponseType");

              options.Scope.Add("openid");
              options.Scope.Add("profile");
              options.Scope.Add("roles");
              options.Scope.Add("fooapi");
              options.Scope.Add("fooidentityapi");
              options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
              options.SaveTokens = true;

              options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
              options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");
              options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");

              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
                  RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
              };
          });

        services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

        // Add Identity Server
        // Add Signing Certificate
        // Add Users Store
        // Add Configurations Store
        // Add Operational Stores
        if (_env.IsDevelopment() || _env.IsStaging())
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddUserStore()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerDataDBConnectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                };
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseSqlServer(identityServerDataDBConnectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                };
            })
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
        }
        else
        {
            //Todo: add certificate
        }
    }

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IWebHostEnvironment env, 
        IOptions<Settings> settingOptions)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(_MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        var forwardOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        };

        forwardOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        forwardOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
}
```

And here's the configuration of API:

```
public class Startup
{
    #region Private Fields
    private readonly string _allowedOrigins = "fooorigin";
    #endregion

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:Authority");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ApiName");
                options.SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Jwt;
            });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        #region Options
        services.AddOptions();
        #endregion

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(_allowedOrigins, builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        });
        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            o.Conventions.Add(new ApiExplorerGroupPerVersionConvention());
            o.Filters.Add(new ModelStateFilter());
        }).AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CommonValidator>();
            fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
        })

        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        #region Customise default API behavour
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Versioning
        services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
        {
            o.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
            o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SwaggerDocOptions:Title"),
                Version = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SwaggerDocOptions:Version"),
                Description = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SwaggerDocOptions:Description")
            });

            c.OperationFilter<RemoveApiVersionFromParamsOperationFilter>();

            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "foo.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

            var scopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:RequiredScopes").Split(',').ToList();
            var scopesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var scope in scopes)
            {
                scopesDictionary.Add(scope, scope);
            }

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    Password = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        TokenUrl = new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:TokenEndpoint")),
                        Scopes = scopesDictionary
                    }
                },
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                        Scheme = "Bearer",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">Application builder</param>
    /// <param name="env">Web host environment</param>
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseCors(_allowedOrigins);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSwagger(
            o =>
            {
                o.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
                {
                    var paths = new OpenApiPaths();
                    foreach (var x in swaggerDoc.Paths)
                    {
                        var key = x.Key.Contains("{version}") ? x.Key.Replace("{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version) : x.Key;
                        paths.Add(key, x.Value);
                    }
                    swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
                    swaggerDoc.Extensions.Add(
                        new KeyValuePair<string,
                        IOpenApiExtension>("x-identity-authority",
                        new OpenApiString(Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:Authority"))));
                });
                o.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/v1.0/swagger.json", "Foo API");
                c.OAuthClientId(Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ClientName"));
                c.OAuthClientSecret(Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:ClientSecret"));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Now let's look at the process of getting an access token:
[image]

When I press "Authorize", it's validating and gets a token:

[image]

but when I try to access API resource which requires an authorization, it returns 401 error:

[image]

I tried to check the same in the Postman and when I try to access token endpoint it returns the access token like that:

[image]

I've been working for hours, tried many things but nothing worked. I tried to provide everything that can be cause of this problem, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `IdentityServerOptions:ApiName` and check the audience of your access token , use jwt.io to decode token .

Comment: I changed client configuration int Identity Server so that now it returns the JWT token, but now I have another issue: 

**www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'clientapi' is invalid".**

I'm not sure why is this invalid do you have any idea about that?

Comment: `clientapi` should be one of the audiences in your access token , that means you should add `clientapi` to scope when acquire token .

Comment: Okay, 'clientapi' was just a generic name, this actually is one of the scopes that are shown the in last picture, **innovatorsnotificationsender** to be specific. I have this one in my required scopes and it is retrieved from **appsettings** when this code is executed:
`var scopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServerOptions:RequiredScopes").Split(',').ToList();` and then it is added to scopes, So I have no idea why is it invalid.

Comment: what is the audience of access token ? Is it include `innovatorsnotificationsender ` ?

Comment: `{
  "nbf": 1581410319,
  "exp": 1581496719,
  "iss": "https://localhost:3001",
  "aud": "innovatorsnotificationsender",
  "client_id": "innovatorsnotificationsenderclient",
  "sub": "d7440b02-c804-416c-891d-337c88afaa5e",
  "auth_time": 1581410319,
  "idp": "local",
  "role": "Admin",
  "username": "admin",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "username",
    "innovatorsnotificationsender",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "custom"
  ]
}`

This is the decoded access token

Answer (score 0):

After researching I found out that the ApiName must be the same as the name of the audience, also we should configure clients for JWT tokens, not the reference tokens.